# Разметка для таблицы в html

Tags: html

Как можно сверстать такую таблицу (только html)?

[image: таблица]

Comment: что значит "как можно сверстать"? Ну берешь и верстаешь, в чем загвоздка?

Comment: @Эникейщик, я просто хочу понять какая здесь должна быть разметка

Comment: ``<table><tr><td>`` ну и так далее. Задай вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, что именно ты хочешь узнать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width="450px">
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" style="background-color: lightgray;">Выбыло</th>
      <th rowspan="4">1 курс</th>
      <td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" style="background-color: lightgray;"></th>
      <th rowspan="4">2 курс</th>
      <td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот так это можно реализовать

Comment: + в сети есть генераторы html-таблиц. Конструируете или выбираете из предложенных визуальную структуру таблицы, а потом просто заполняете предоставленный Вам html-скелет таблицы